# NextJS Track Mounted Components in SSR

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, next.js, react-context

The following applies to SSR via NextJS.

I'm using React's context to keep track of IDs of certain mounted components. The gist is

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  getChildContext () {
    return {
      registerComponent: this.registerComponent
    }
  }

  registerComponent = (id) => {
    this.setState(({ mountedComponents }) => {
      return { mountedComponents: [...mountedComponents, id ] }
    })
  }

  ...
}

class ChildComponent {
  static contextTypes = { registerComponent: PropTypes.func }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    props.registerComponent(props.id)
  }
}
```

unfortunately this only works client-side. `this.state.mountedComponents` is always `[]` on the server. Is there another way to track these components *server-side*? Basically I need the ids to provide to a script to run in the `head` of the document - waiting until the client app mounts, runs, and appends to the head manually is a little too slow.

**update**

here's a quick example repo: https://github.com/tills13/nextjs-ssr-context

`this.context` is `undefined` in the constructor of `Child`, if I move it to `componentDidMount` (currently set up this way in the repo), it works, but I'd like this to be resolved server-side. I'm not dead-set on `context`, if there's another way to do this, I'm all ears.

Comment: Which version of nextjs are you using? These context's APIs were experimental. With react 16 there are new APIs.

Comment: I'm using Next 6.0. "New" context APIs (`React.createContext`) don't work at all in SSR. Discussed in https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4182 / https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4194

Comment: try moving the function call to componentDidMount from the constructor

Comment: @gandharvgarg that defeats the purpose as `componentDidMount` only runs clientside. I need this to be done serverside.

Comment: @TarunLalwani updated

Answer (score 3):

I have dig into this and my feeling is that this is not possible for multiple reason.

The `setState` update is async and won't be executed in your case.

The render of your `provider` will happen even before the state gets updated, so registration code will be execute later and the render function doesn't have the latest state

I put different `console.log` and below is what I got

```
Provider constructed with { mountedComponents: [],
  name: 'name-Sun Jun 24 2018 19:19:08 GMT+0530 (IST)' }
getDerivedStateFromProps
Renderring Provider Component { mountedComponents: [],
  name: 'name-Sun Jun 24 2018 19:19:08 GMT+0530 (IST)' }
data loaded
constructor Child { id: '1' } { registerComponent: [Function: value] }
Register Component called 1 { mountedComponents: [],
  name: 'name-Sun Jun 24 2018 19:19:08 GMT+0530 (IST)' }
Registering component 1
constructor Child { id: '2' } { registerComponent: [Function: value] }
Register Component called 2 { mountedComponents: [ '1' ],
  name: 'tarun-Sun Jun 24 2018 19:19:08 GMT+0530 (IST)' }
Registering component 2
constructor Child { id: '3' } { registerComponent: [Function: value] }
Register Component called 3 { mountedComponents: [ '1', '2' ],
  name: 'name-Sun Jun 24 2018 19:19:08 GMT+0530 (IST)' }
Registering component 3
constructor Child { id: '4' } { registerComponent: [Function: value] }
Register Component called 4 { mountedComponents: [ '1', '2', '3' ],
  name: 'name-Sun Jun 24 2018 19:19:08 GMT+0530 (IST)' }
Registering component 4
```

The information is actually only available when the `componentDidMount` occurs. But since in case of server side rendering that doesn't happen, you don't get the data.

I am digging further to see if any hacks are available, but as of now I am not sure

Answer (score 2):

Using the *context* API inside the contructor is possible, you just need to pass it as a parameter inside both the **constructor** and the **super** method as below:

```
export class Child extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = { registerComponent: PropTypes.func };

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    context.registerComponent(props.id);
  }

  render() {
    return <div id={this.props.id} />;
  }
}
```

**update:**
so, the problem is related to the first render on the *server* that doesn't support any interractivity,
this approche will prevent any `setState` to be considered on the *server*, in your example the `<Provider />` 
wouldn't give as any hand, so we need a workaround that will be a hack in any case.

the solution i got is having a new `window.ids` with every tracked component render(using the Head provided from nextjs):

```
export class Child extends React.Component {
  registerComponent = (id) => `
    if (window.ids) {
      window.ids = [...window.ids, ${id}];
    } else window.ids = [${id}];
  `;

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Head>
          <script
            className="track"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `${this.registerComponent(this.props.id)}`,
            }}
          />
        </Head>
        <div id={this.props.id} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

so the `window.ids` variable will be available before the `<App /> renders`.
here is a [repos link](https://github.com/ItsTarik/nextjs-ssr-context) to test it.

one other solution could be using a **global variable** on the server, then in each tracked component we could mutate
that global varibale using the **componentWillMount** life cycle hook since it will be executed on the server only, then
inject those ids on the html template `<head />`, but this is possible if we are executing the renderToString method.

**second solution**: using the pages/**_document** instead of pages/**_app** so we get access to the server `before it renders to string!`:
this is the repo branch: [origin/workaround-using-document](https://github.com/ItsTarik/nextjs-ssr-context/tree/workaround-using-document)

-Child component:

```
export class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Head>
          <meta className="track" id={this.props.id} />
        </Head>
        <div id={this.props.id} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

-Document Component(replacing the App):

```
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    const { head } = this.props;
    const idsFromHead = head.reduce(
      (acc, { props }) =>
        (props.className.includes('track') && [...acc, props.id]) || acc,
      []
    );

    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `window.ids=[${idsFromHead}]`,
            }}
          />
        </Head>
        <body className="custom_class">
          <h3>{idsFromHead}</h3>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

this approche works 100% on the server since we could capture the tracked ids before server rendrering occurs.
[image]

but the `<NextScript />` is generating a warning(don't know why, could be a bug from nextjs):
[image]

Comment: What you say is correct, but have you tested to see if this really solves the problem?

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes even the `<Provider />` will be first rendred before any tracked component, i have a work around so i will update the response with details.

Comment: hm. interesting - as it stands, that second method works but has wonky behaviour between page transitions.

Comment: yup, the hydration transition is bizarre, if i remove the ```<NextScript />``` i will get a clean html SSR rendred with the ```<head>``` tag(usefull to inject scripts, styles and metadata) and without warnings, but without react components on the dom, even the pages/_app.js document uses the ```<NextScript />``` under the hood to inject the bundled js to bring life to dead components, something is not ok with next!

Comment: @TylerSebastian, tried to dig more on that warning but i couldn't reproduce it again, it has been disappeared and i think it was related to some cashed things!, i just get an HMR warning in firefox, but it is ok with chrome, could you verify that ?